# How might I have methods with different return types based on the reciever?

Tags: go

I have the following interface:

```
type ExampleInterface interface{
    GetFirstItemInSlice()
}

func GetFirstItemInSlice(slice ExampleInterface){
    slice.GetFirstItemInSlice()
}

func (slice IntSlice) GetFirstItemInSlice(){
    // Omitted for brevity.
}

func (slice StringSlice) GetFirstItemInSlice(){
    // Omitted for brevity.
}
```

Now, it is clear here, that my two functions which have recievers (the bottom two), will want to return different types, one a string, and the other, an int. If I just tack on a return type, then it will break my interface, right?

I assume this is a common problem, and I am missing some key knowledge component on interfaces, All help appreciated.

Please note : I would rather not return an interface, I would REALLY love to return a piece of typed data.

Comment: Change function names appropriately, don't use same similar function names for everything.

Comment: Trying to return two different types would not satisfy the interface in first place. I don't think there is any other way, rather than return interface and find type in required function through switch case.

Comment: Wait, there is a way to find the correct type via a switch?!

Comment: yes, look over [here](https://newfivefour.com/golang-interface-type-assertions-switch.html) and [here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) for examples.

Comment: You are trying traditional OOP in Go. You will hurt yourself. It might be better to come up with a sensible example because getting the first element in a slice in Go is done by `s[0]` and not through a Javaesque `GetCopyOfFirstElemntOfANonNilSliceWithoutModifyingTheSlice`

Answer (score 2):

> How might I have methods with different return types based on the reciever?

**TL;DR;** You can't.

Longer answer: There are roughly three options to accomplish what you're describing. You probably won't like any of them.

1. Return an interface

   ```
   type ExampleInterface interface{
       GetFirstItemInSlice() interface{}
   }
   ```

   Then, of course, it's up to each caller to assert back to the underlying type.
2. Use different return types.

   ```
   type IntInterface interface{
       GetFirstIntInSlice() int
   }

   type StringInterface interface {
       GetFirstStringSlice() string
   }
   ```
3. Don't return, but instead use reflection to modify a passed in variable.

   ```
   type ExampleInterface interface{
       GetFirstItemInSlice(interface{})
   }
   ```

   This is the most complex one to write, and is almost certainly overkill for something as simple as returning an int or a slice. But it does have use for more complex data structures, and is the approach taken by things like the standard library's [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) unmarshaling.  In this case, the caller would pass in a pointer to an allocated variable, which the method would then set, using reflection.  The calling code might look like:

   ```
   var foo int
   ei.GetFirstItemInSlice(&foo)
   ```

A fourth option, and probably the best in your particular situation, is a refactor so that none of the above is necessary. Without understanding your larger problem, though, I cannot offer a specific, concrete suggestion on how to do this in your case.